# Optimal way of passing data from a filter to a controller?

Tags: grails, filter, controller

Hi there in part of our application i need to pass data from a filter to a controller. I have read that this can be done by using a request object and a before interceptor on the controller.

Some example code:

```
class SomeService {
    def doSomething(request, params) {
        request.foo = "helloworld"
    }
}

class SomeFilter {

    def someService

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                // service does something and places object in request
                // using request.foo = "helloworld"
                someService.doSomething(request, params)
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeController {

    def foo

    def beforeInterceptor = {
        foo = request.foo
    }

    def index = { 
        println foo
    }
}
```

Is this an efficient way of doing things or are there other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're using (assigning the data to a request attribute) is efficient and a widely used way to communicate request specific data between layers.

The Spring framework that grails is based on uses this extensively.  You can see some of the attribute keys it uses here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.html

Comment: I guess it is good practice to use minimal objects in the request attribute. Should i use it for a domain object for example? Like a User or should i pass the UserId in the request object? When passing the full object from filter to controller it would save me a database request. Any thoughts in this?

Comment: Minimal objects is probably a good goal.  I would generally avoid domain objects as it can lead to difficult to debug hibernate session and transaction error situations.